# ClickOnce installation interrupting due to certificate query

Tags: installation, browser, certificate, client, clickonce

In Edge when trying to install/update a fresh ClickOnce application from a https link, some users get a prompt of "Select a certificate".
[Select a certificate dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GchMp.jpg)
This will interrupt the installation process. After that in ClickOnce log there is a 403 Forbidden error that says that a download of specific deploy file failed.

From [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/server-and-client-configuration-issues-in-clickonce-deployments?view=vs-2022) I found following:

> ClickOnce and Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)
> A ClickOnce application will work fine over SSL, except when Internet Explorer raises a prompt about the SSL certificate. The prompt can be raised when there is something wrong with the certificate, such as when the site names do not match or the certificate has expired. To make ClickOnce work over an SSL connection, make sure that the certificate is up-to-date, and that the certificate data matches the site data.

The software is signed with a temporary certificate. Software is installed against IIS.

Is there some workaround to prevent certificate query of the browser? If not in Edge itself, some registry setting related to ClickOnce applications or certificate queries? I was able to see that at least one user did not get the prompt at all and software was installed successfully immediately.

As a workaround asked to try launch application until it succeeds installing everything, but it may require 50 attempts. Alternatively it's possible to just distribute the application through a separate zip file from same site. It will download zip file without the certificate prompt. After unzipping, the software can be installed successfully as well even for users that got certificate prompt through Edge.

We also tried registry setting "SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls" with a generic value of
{"pattern": "[*.]","filter":{}}
to get rid of the certificate prompt, but it didn't help installing the software.

Comment: Hey @Nakano , did you ever resolve this issue? My organization is running into the same problem at the moment

Comment: Unfortunately no solution for the actual cause with the customer organization. I had to proceed with a workaround. I manually build the client package. Any user having a problem downloads the zip file from a html page, which is the same page as the application would be normally started, unzip it on their machine and installs it. They will also start the application from their machice.

This is a cumbersome process from both ends but luckily there hasn't been a need to update the build yet.